# Wrinkling in flat UV

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

Adjusted a model to accomodate a few holes. For some reason there is a wrinkling in the applied UV. I went in and tried eliminate any overlapping uv's that may have produced this issue. I cant seam to figure out the cause when rendering.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

[image]I was able to solve this issue by creating a new edge using the knife tool to intercept the weirdly interpreted anchor points.